# Cloudera Impala: File has an invalid version number. This could be due to stale metadata

Tags: azure, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, impala, parquet

I am running a **CDH** distribution (version 5.6.0) with **Impala** (version 2.4.0).

I have some Parquet files stored in HDFS. Next, I have loaded these files into an Impala external table with the following query:

```
create external table parquetTable
like parquet 'hdfs://cloudera-impala-mn0.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:8020/user/root/big_data/part-r-00015-66cf01ca-ffee-4a62-b2c3-c09177ec4bd7.gz.parquet'
stored as parquet location 'hdfs://cloudera-impala-mn0.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:8020/user/root/big_data/;
```

Upon executing the following query all the files are successfully listed:

```
[cloudera-impala-dn0.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:21000] > show files in parquettable;
```

Also, the metadata is correct (checked by executing `describe parquettable`).

The stats of the table are:

```
[cloudera-impala-dn0.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:21000] > show table stats parquettable;
```

> Rows | Files | Size     | Bytes Cached | Cache Replication | Format  | Incremental stats | Location
>
> -1 | 838    | 249.64GB | NOT CACHED   | NOT CACHED        | PARQUET | false             | hdfs://cloudera-impala-mn0.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:8020/user/root/big_data

Executing the following query:

```
[cloudera-impala-dn0.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:21000] > select count(*) from parquettable;
```

results in the following **WARNING**, but without any output result or error:

> File 'hdfs://cloudera-impala-mn0.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:8020/user/root/big_data/part-r-00001-7c29b85c-bd1f-420e-8834-96300076a92d.gz.parquet' has an invalid version number: ▒.F/
>   This could be due to stale metadata. Try running "refresh default.parquettable".

Running `refresh default.parquettable` did not have any effect.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you try to run "invalidate metadata" command in impala shell and try the query again?

Comment: @Lan I've tried that too, but still no success. The warning message remains the same and no output.

Comment: How do you create the parquet based table?

Comment: @Lan I updated the problem description to include the table creation query.

Comment: Your steps look good. Now the error complains about part-r-00001-7c29b85c-bd1f-420e-8834-96300076a92d.gz.parquet, while you use part-r-00015-66cf01ca-ffee-4a62-b2c3-c09177ec4bd7.gz.parquet when creating the table. So is the problem in part-r-00001-7c29b85c-bd1f-420e-8834-96300076a92d.gz.parquet? Can you get rid of all files in the big_data table except part-r-00015-66cf01ca-ffee-4a62-b2c3-c09177ec4bd7.gz.parquet ?

Comment: Also how do you create these parquet files?

Comment: @Lan you were right, the problem was related to those files. I first ignored this option because the same files are successfully queried with SparkSQL.

Comment: @Lan the files were created via a Spark cluster that appended and modified the contents of a big file to the same file, thus increasing its size.

Comment: @Lan Thanks for this hint. I cannot mark your comment as the right answer, but I will should you provide one (not as a comment).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your steps look good. The error complains about part-r-00001-7c29b85c-bd1f-420e-8834-96300076a92d.gz.parquet, while you use part-r-00015-66cf01ca-ffee-4a62-b2c3-c09177ec4bd7.gz.parquet when creating the table. So it looks like there is a problem in part-r-00001-7c29b85c-bd1f-420e-8834-96300076a92d.gz.parquet. Can you get rid of all files in the big_data table except part-r-00015-66cf01ca-ffee-4a62-b2c3-c09177ec4bd7.gz.parquet?

Comment: How is that the accepted answer ? It should be a comment as it just asks a question and does not provide any solution at all.